# Execute command when UI window is closed | Maya/Python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya, autodesk

Here’s one I’m hoping should be quite simple:

How can I get my UI window to execute a command when the user closes the window?
I’ve created a scriptJob that runs while the window is open and I’d like to run a command to terminate it when the window is closed, and avoid having any scriptJobs running when the tool isn’t in use.

Using Python in Maya2020
Any pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code for creating the window and binding your `scriptJob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `parent`parameter to the scriptJob command to attach the scriptJob to an UI element, have a look at the docs: `parent - Attaches this job to a piece of maya UI. When the UI is destroyed, the job will be killed along with it.`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need.